# Restful Jetty HTTP ERROR 404 accessing not found

Tags: java, rest, jetty, embedded-jetty

Here is my url; http://localhost:2222/test1/test1/home/hello

This url causes the error below.
**HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /test1/test1/home/hello. Reason:
    Not Found**

And main servlet starter and resource class below

```
 ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages("java"); // this is where my main class and resource resides
    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));


    Server server = new Server(2222);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/test1",ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(servlet,"/test1");
    try
    {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        server.destroy();
    }
```

My Resource

```
@Path("/home")
public class Resources {

@GET
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:I think problem is in "packages" part but i dont know how to configure it.
Thanks

Comment: Let's keep comments civil please.

Answer (score 0):

You created a `ServletContextHandler` but didn't add it to the server.

Add ...

```java
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(context);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
server.setHandler(handlers);
```